# Why no DateTime.Add(DateTime) method when there is one for Subtract?

Tags: c#, .net, api

Why is there no [`DateTime.Add(DateTime)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.add?view=netstandard-2.0) overload when there is a [`DateTime.Subtract(DataTime)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=netstandard-2.0) overload?

Given the similarity of Add and Subtract operations, I would expect they would have the same overloads. Why might this not be the case?

Comment: What would you expect as a result of adding two dates? Subtracting them can give you a difference but adding 2019-10-01 to 2019-10-01 just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Maybe they're not as similar as it seemed at first glance.

Comment: What you're looking for is something like `DateTime.Date.AddDays()` or one of those functions. How could you add `January 1st 2019` to `January 01 2020`? You have to add measurements to a date.

Comment: I believe Karl-JohanSjögren and RufusL give the best answers. Just because Add and Subtract are very similar in mathematics does not imply that using the same verbs in temporal context make them similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between two `DateTime` objects is `TimeSpan` object. `Subtract(DateTime)` returns `TimeSpan`, `Subtract(TimeSpan)` returns `DateTime`.

However, you can increase `DateTime` by `TimeSpan` (an interval) value or using `AddDays()`, `AddMonths()`, etc. methods, adding two `DateTime` objects doesn't make sense in terms of result

Comment: You can also DateTime.AddDays(), DateTime.AddMonths(), and so on.

Comment: Not going to downvote, as there's some good info here, but this **does not** answer the OP question. I wish I knew why, because this is plain stupid. Let's imagine working with numbers: `double` + `int` = `double` but `int` + `double` = compiler error. Does this make sense? Nope! Then why does `DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)` work but `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) + DateTime.Now` fails to compile?

Answer (score 2):

I agree, it's a deficiency - so let's give a go at sorting it out! :)

```
static class Ext
{
    public static DateTime Add(this DateTime one, DateTime two)
    {
        return new DateTime(one.Ticks + two.Ticks);
    }
}
```

There are a few things that could go wrong with this, of course, but we'll ignore overflows or timezone issues for a moment. Now we've got the tool, we kinda need to think of a use case for it..

```
    public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("It's " + (DateTime.UtcNow.Add(DateTime.UtcNow)));
}

    --> It's 7/1/4038 6:10:06 PM
```

Hmm.. Soo.. I'll have a think on how to make it useful and get back to you..

Tongue in cheek aside, this is perhaps a good way to demonstrate that if we feel the framework lacks something we need as a simplistic operation, we can add it in as an extension, even if we can't subclass the existing class. It might make sense to be able to find the date half way between two dates, for example:

```
static class Ext
{
    public static DateTime HalfWayTo(this DateTime one, DateTime two)
    {
        return new DateTime(Math.Abs(one.Ticks + two.Ticks)/2);
    }
}
```

That might have a use case.. And if you think of one for the straight Add, let me know..